# Why is the camera / photo quality of 2021 Moto g stylus 5g is worse than my 2016 samsung s7?

Tags: camera, photos, motorola-moto-g, samsung-galaxy-s7

I just upgraded my Samsung s7 to moto g stylus 5g (2021). Moto g stylus 5g 2021 has 4 camera's advertising a 48MP camera - but to my jaw dropping surprise the quality of pictures coming out of this 2021 camera is nearly equivalent, on the worse side than my 2016 S7? When I zoom into the pictures (I have made sure conditions are normalized and equivalent for taking the photos for each camera) the s7 images for the same 12MP resolution look sharper and clearer hands down. What good is the additional 3 cameras on Moto g? Where is the rest of the power of this 48MP camera (vs s7's lone 12MP sensor)? What could the reason be for this surprising lack of improvement (more like digression) from the 2016 technology with far fewer sensors? I am completely baffled. Am I missing something fundamental about perhaps limitations posed by the Android OS on the camera systems (I have tried every conceivable camera setting, so that's not an issue)? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kind of related: [How does software affect photo quality on different Android devices even though they have the same camera sensor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/164870/44325), [Does camera clarity vary with to the app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26997/44325). Hardware is not the only thing that matters. Also the comment discussion on [Can any Google Pixel smartphones take 12MP or better photos in 16:9 aspect ratio?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/237050/44325).

Comment: May be because your new phone is much cheaper than your old phone? And having multiple cameras does not imply that one of them is making great pictures. Especially on low light cheap cameras tend to make low quality pictures.

Comment: Thanks @Robert - I can understand the "cheaper" vs "more expensive" argument to some extent.  Moto g stylus 5G maybe  cheaper, but not in the hello kitty kids phone category either. Considering the fast evolving technology space like phones and cameras and number of years in between these phones,  I feel like the time gradient (2016 vs 2021)  should've easily beaten the price gradient. Something still doesn't quite  feel right that Moto g Stylus 5G class phone claiming a 48MP camera in 2021 is unable to produce as good a picture as the 2016 s7's 12MP camera.